# How to send Indy request with DELETE methode and JSON stream source in Delphi 7?

Tags: json, request, delphi-7

I have a problem in sending web service request using Delphi 7 and Indy. My workplace a public hospital as a client and insurance third party as the server. Here is the service catalogue:

```
   URL : {BASE URL from the insurance office}/Delete
    Method : DELETE
    Format : Json
    Content-Type: Application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Request body : 
        {"request": {"t_obj": {"noObj": "0301X1018V001","user": "myUser"}}}
```

I use Indy 10.6 and some of the code I wrote is:

```
   Json := '{"request": {"t_obj": {"noObj": "0301X1018V001","user": "myUser"}}}';
   req := TStringStream.Create(Utf8Encode(Json)); 
   resp := TStringStream.Create('');

   IdHttp1.request.Source := req;
   IdHttp1.Request.ContentType := 'Application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
   IdHttp1.delete('{BASE URL from the insurance office}/Delete', resp);
   showmessage(resp.DataString);
```

But, when the request sent, it failed to delete.
Any one can help me, please? I'm sorry my English is not good enough.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is not a valid media type for sending JSON. Are you sure the server is not actually expecting `application/json` instead? It should be.

Beside that, a more important reason why your request does not work is because the `TIdHTTP.Delete()` method simply does not allow sending a post body, so the server never sees the JSON at all.  Internally, `Delete()` calls the `TIdCustomHTTP.DoRequest()` method passing `nil` in the `ASource` parameter, which replaces your assignment of the `TIdHTTP.Request.Source` property.

To do what you are attempting, you will have to call `DoRequest()` directly, eg:

```
// TIdCustomHTTP.DoRequest() is protected,
// so use an accessor class to reach it...
type
  TIdHTTPAccess = class(TIdHTTP)
  end;

...

Json := '{"request": {"t_obj": {"noObj": "0301X1018V001","user": "myUser"}}}';
req := TStringStream.Create(UTF8Encode(Json));
try
  resp := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    //IdHttp1.Request.Source := req;
    //IdHttp1.Request.ContentType := 'Application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    IdHttp1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    //IdHttp1.Delete('{BASE URL from the insurance office}/Delete', resp);
    TIdHTTPAccess(IdHttp1).DoRequest(Id_HTTPMethodDelete, '{BASE URL from the insurance office}/Delete', req, resp, []);
    ShowMessage(resp.DataString);
  finally
    resp.Free;
  end;
finally
  req.Free;
end;
```